# How to copyright 3D models

Tags: united-states, copyright, intellectual-property

As practice, and for a fun project, I made a 3D model of a set of special dice that are intended to be used for a specific game I invented. I plan to share and refine the work over time but before I go public I want to ensure that the idea can't be used commercially but can be shared freely (basically [Creative-Commons Sharealike NonCommericial](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/)).

How do you license a work like a 3D model and its associated gameplay material in such a manner that it has legal grounding? Would I need to file a copyright?

Answer (score 1):

Copyrights are automatic - legally, you get the copyright as soon as the work is fixed, whether or not you register the copyright.  But registration gives you some extra protections.

You can't copyright the *idea* of your game.  Copyrights are for works, not ideas, after all.  You can copyright your model, assuming it's not something too obvious like a model of an ordinary pair of dice.  It needs at least a little bit of creativity.

Licensing your work can be done however you like.  If you think a CC BY-NC-SA license is appropriate, feel free to use that license.

Comment: One addition, the design of the dice themselves could be protected by a protected design, a trademark, or even a patent; depending on how novel your design is.